# C# using same code page to encoding byte array into string has different results in US locale and Japan locale

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, locale, zlib

```
public void foo(byte[] data)
{
    var str = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetString(data);
    PINVOKE.DoSomething(out unmanagedPtr, str, data.length)
}
```

The code convert byte array to string and use P/Invoke to call a C layer function which will take a unsigned char array and create an un-managed object based on byte array. Because C doesn't have byte array, I have to convert data to string.

The problem is this function works fine in EMEA and NAM with English locale, but fails on Japan locale. 
Error is ZLIB decompression error-  Data error. Input data is corrupted.

156 'œ', 140 'Œ' (executed in US locale) are mapped to 63 '?' (Japan locale); 226 'â' is mapped to 97 'a'.

Comment: You *really* don't want to be using a string here. Find a way of passing the byte array directly to the unmanaged function.

Comment: read this here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332097(v=vs.71).aspx and it will state specifically about `Japan` and why the differences you are seeing

Comment: @MethodMan but I am trying to use 1252 in Japan locale not the other way around.

Comment: what about Encoding based on CultureInfo.. have you looked into that.. I am not sure because everything I write over here deals with `US` Culture

Comment: @MethodMan Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"); but it doesn't work. I have a feeling that the encoding is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I can avoid encoding part but pass the bytes array directly to the P\Invoke method. Just need to change the signature of the P\Invoke method to take byte[] instead string.

But I still want to know why using same code page gives different results in different locale settings!